# Show only the name (minus the namespace) for GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a WinForm application that have GridControl that are bind to a property. The property is of class Type. Something like this:

```
public class AvailableUpdate
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that in the UI it's showing the full Type's name - including the namespace. How do I show only the name, minus the namespace?

For testing sake, I have also tried decorating it with System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute:

```
    [DisplayName("aofoej")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
```

This doesn't work either...

Comment: can you add property `public string TypeName => this.Type?.Name;` to your `AvailableUpdate` class?

Comment: Yes, and it worked. Never occurred to me to just create another property, that was so simple.

Comment: Glad that helps. Btw, there is no special magic in `ComponentModel`s attributes like `DisplayNameAttribute`. They originaly invented for use with WinForm's components and are used by Visual Studio itself.